# Ambiguous Column SQL error when using a concatenated field

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am buidling an app in CakePHP. I have 2 models:
- Project
- User

The Project model has various belongsTo relations to the user model, one for the creator, one for the last editor and one for the manager. This works fine.

Then I add a virtual field to the User model, called 'name', which is CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name). It combines the first name and last name into a general name field, which is used througout the app.

After this, I get SQL errors saying that the first_name column is ambiguous. This is because in the query, the alias for Creator, Manager, etc is not used in the CONCAT field.

Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1632/Virtual-fields-and-model-aliases

Answer (score 2):

Showing the exact queries should help resolve this problem.  But if you are joining 2 tables, and they both have a column with the same name. you have to reference the column with TableName.ColumnName, like this.

```
Select Table1.Column1 AS someColumn, Table2.Column1 AS SomeOtherColumn
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID
WHERE Table1.ID = 3
```

You can shorten this up by giving your tables aliases, As follows.

```
Select T1.Column1 AS someColumn, T2.Column1 AS SomeOtherColumn
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2  AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.Table1ID
WHERE T1.ID = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that that's how it should be done in the query, but I wonder how I can make CakePHP produce a query like that. The virtualField is defined in the Contact model.

Comment: If it's CakePHP you're using, then you may want to look at this other question.  If you are trying to specify a condition on your concatenated column, this may help out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310317/two-similar-cakephp-data-retrieval-queries-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying what table the first_name column is from.  Something like this:

```
CONCAT(table1.first_name,'',table1.last_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that that's how it should be done in the query, but I wonder how I can make CakePHP produce a query like that. The virtualField is defined in the Contact model.